# How to make VSCode break long lines of JavaScript down without resorting to Prettier or Standard?

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-formatting

I'm trying to transition from JetBrains IDEs to Visual Studio Code, but I'm running into an issue with formatting JavaScript. When an assignment statement is over the line length limit, the VSCode formatter just says "this is fine" and leaves it alone, whereas JetBrains IDEs will break it down into individual lines, so this

```js
const runningContainers = [{ "ID": "b271973b550db0a2b51f434888fb0403bd145c9474c1bb88a26e332b4cece9eb", "Name": "frontend-vue2_front_e2e_1", "Image": "frontend-vue2_front_e2e", "Command": "docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/supervisord", "Project": "frontend-vue2", "Service": "front_e2e", "Created": 1683451465, "State": "running", "Status": "Up 5 minutes", "Health": "", "ExitCode": 0, "Publishers": [{ "URL": "0.0.0.0", "TargetPort": 3000, "PublishedPort": 3011, "Protocol": "tcp" }] }, { "ID": "c25ae4df4be687344737c531d6c232a75bb1f3fd03f9d76169ab078957f10f8b", "Name": "frontend-vue2_frontend_1", "Image": "frontend-vue2_frontend", "Command": "docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/supervisord", "Project": "frontend-vue2", "Service": "frontend", "Created": 1683451465, "State": "running", "Status": "Up 5 minutes", "Health": "", "ExitCode": 0, "Publishers": [{ "URL": "0.0.0.0", "TargetPort": 3000, "PublishedPort": 3010, "Protocol": "tcp" }] }]
```

becomes this

```js
const runningContainers = [{
  "ID": "b271973b550db0a2b51f434888fb0403bd145c9474c1bb88a26e332b4cece9eb",
  "Name": "frontend-vue2_front_e2e_1",
  "Image": "frontend-vue2_front_e2e",
  "Command": "docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/supervisord",
  "Project": "frontend-vue2",
  "Service": "front_e2e",
  "Created": 1683451465,
  "State": "running",
  "Status": "Up 5 minutes",
  "Health": "",
  "ExitCode": 0,
  "Publishers": [{ "URL": "0.0.0.0", "TargetPort": 3000, "PublishedPort": 3011, "Protocol": "tcp" }],
}, {
  "ID": "c25ae4df4be687344737c531d6c232a75bb1f3fd03f9d76169ab078957f10f8b",
  "Name": "frontend-vue2_frontend_1",
  "Image": "frontend-vue2_frontend",
  "Command": "docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/supervisord",
  "Project": "frontend-vue2",
  "Service": "frontend",
  "Created": 1683451465,
  "State": "running",
  "Status": "Up 5 minutes",
  "Health": "",
  "ExitCode": 0,
  "Publishers": [{ "URL": "0.0.0.0", "TargetPort": 3000, "PublishedPort": 3010, "Protocol": "tcp" }],
}];
```

I *only* want it to make this change. I do *not* want to use Prettier, as Prettier has Opinions, and some non-configurable opinions differ from the preferred code style for this project. The same goes for Standard: it is too opinionated. Both will make far too many changes to the project, rather than just breaking down long lines the way I want.

eslint will happily tell me the line is too long, but it doesn't offer any Quick Fix actions to reformat it.

Is there a way to get VSCode to acknowledge that the line of code is over the line length limit, and actually *do* something about it? Surely there must be an extension which *just* does this — or is everybody but me signed up to the cult of Prettier these days?

Comment: you have to use a formatter, choose one that has this feature and be able to disable all other stuff, or write your own JavaScript formatter, not that difficult

Comment: why is `Publishers` not split into multiple lines

Comment: humm, (when) intelliJ is so cool...what do they use for "javascript formatting" (in UE)?? ;);) (hint: so hyped prettier!;)

Comment: the "default/built-in" (type-/javascript) formatter has no "line length" settings, as it looks

Comment: @rioV8 The last time I tried to write a VSCode extension I found the documentation to be very unhelpful. Maybe MS has improved it since then. (`Publishers` is not split into multiple lines because the current line comes in under the line length limit, which I set at 120 characters as I am not using a VT220 any more :)

Comment: @xerx593 I don't know quite what you mean by "in UE", but RubyMine will certainly let me configure *way* more about how my code should look than Prettier does, so I doubt it's using that.

Comment: ue = ultimate edition (intellij, diefferent product, https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/prettier.html) but same applies to rubyMine: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/prettier.html

Comment: there are a lot of example extensions that show how to use a particular API function, you have to browse the API reference page to find what is possible.

Comment: @xerx593 Sure, that page says Prettier is bundled and you *can* use it. It's not on by default, though, and is disabled in my setup. When Prettier is not enabled, RubyMine uses its own formatter, which does the correct thing — and allows the *user* to choose what the correct thing is, which Prettier does not (apart from a few minor things — and the authors say they wish they hadn't even allowed *those* to be configurable!) I definitely want to be the one to make those choices, not somebody else!

Comment: Sorry, i see no/don't find the according option in vscode default formatter